# Как сравнивать каждое слово друг с другом в предложения в C++

Tags: c++, строки

//Присвоить переменной F значение true, если в предложении S1 есть хотя бы одно слово, которое отсутствует в предложении S2 , и false – в противном случае.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool find(char*, char*);
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char S1[] = "Тест сегодня будет";
    char S2[] = "Тест сегодня будет отличным";
    cout << S1 << endl;
    cout << S2 << endl;
    bool F = find(S1, S2);
    cout << boolalpha << F;
}
bool find(char* S1, char* S2) {
    char* p;
    char* pp;
    for (p = strtok_s(S1, " ", &pp); p; p = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &pp)){
        if (strstr(S2, p) == NULL) 
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Программа будет выводить false, если в предложении S2 соединить соединить первые 2 слова(Тест сегодня). Как я понял, программа сравнивает слово с предложением, как сделать так, чтобы слово сравнивалось с каждым словом?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала пишете и отлаживаете функцию, которая строку разбивает на слова. Например:

```
std::vector<std::string> split( const char *str );
```

Далее получаете два списка слов. Проходите по циклу по первому списку и ищете каждое слово во втором. Если не найдено сразу возвращаете `true`, если найдено продолжаете искать. Если цикл завершился, возвращаете `false`. Функцию поиска можете написать сами или использовать `std::find`. Либо используйте контейнер со встроенным поиском для второй последовательности - `std::unordered_set<std::string>` к примеру.